# TypeScript strictNullChecks don't seem to carry type inferences/assertions to synchronous child scopes

Tags: typescript

With `strictNullChecks` enabled, is it a known limitation of TypeScript that synchronous callbacks (such as those provided to `Array.forEach`) do not inherit the type assertions & inferences made in the parent scope? I'm struggling to understand why I'm receiving a `TS2351: Object is possibly 'null'.` error in the minimal repro code below.

This is with TypeScript 3.1.3.

```ts
class Foo {
    bar = 'bar';
}

const array = new Array(2);
let foo: Foo | null;
foo = new Foo();

function bar() {
    if (foo === null) {
        return;
    }

    // This can be any synchronously-invoked callback.
    // `forEach` is only one example.
    array.forEach(item => {
        // Because of the check on line 10,
        // it is not possible for `foo` to be `null` here.
        // However, we still get `TS2351: Object is possibly 'null'.`
        console.log(foo.bar);
    });
}
```

[Link to this same code on the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%20%3D%20'bar'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20array%20%3D%20new%20Array(2)%3B%0D%0Alet%20foo%3A%20Foo%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0Afoo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20bar()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(foo%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20can%20be%20any%20synchronously-invoked%20callback.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%60forEach%60%20is%20only%20one%20example.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20array.forEach(item%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Because%20of%20the%20check%20on%20line%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20it%20is%20not%20possible%20for%20%60foo%60%20to%20be%20%60null%60%20here.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20However%2C%20we%20still%20get%20%60TS2351%3A%20Object%20is%20possibly%20'null'.%60%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(foo.bar)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) (you still need to manually click "Options" and enable `strictNullChecks`).

Comment: [Related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8270). From there: *[...] control flow analysis doesn't consider a type guard to hold across a callback (because the callback could happen at any time, including outside the guarded block).* afaik typescript doesn't have the capability to distinguish between synchronous and asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: In other words, ‘array.forEach’ can potentially (in theory) change ‘foo’ before invoking the passed callback. Yes, the flow analysis isnt smart enough, I guess thats the main diff when compared to flowlang. Just cast ‘foo = foo as Foo’.

Comment: The [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) may also be quite useful here.

Comment: Thanks. This helps me understand the limitations.